# binding datatable columns into class model

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `DataTable` and a `Model`. Are there any other ways on how to map the columns on the members of the class? Let me illustrate my current way,

class Model

```
private class MyModel
{
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

and a `DataTable` with the following data column,

```
ModelID   |   ModelName
```

The records f the `Datatable` is from teh result of my sql query.

```
SELECT ModelID, ModelName FROM tableName
```

Now, when I map the records to `IList<MyModel> myList`, I do a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (DataRow row in MyDataTable)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel()
    model.ModelID = Convert.ToInt32(row["Position"].ToString());
    model.ModelName = row["ModelName"].ToString(); 
    myList.Add(model);
}
```

and this totally works fine. This is not really a problem but it is very time consuming considering that i have many data tables and has *20 columns* or more, and many more classes.

What I am looking for is if there are other ways to do it. Like an existing class but I really don't know what's its name.

If this question has already been asked, please help me find the link.

Thank you.

Comment: What about EF or NHibernate?

Comment: @JleruOHeP That's good but I did not started this project.

Comment: how about this? http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) should be able to do this, though you'll want to test how efficient it is.  [This post](http://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/) seems to have some success with it:

```
public class Person
{
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
}

List<Person> people = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, 
                      List<Person>>(sourceDataTable.CreateDataReader());
```

Note that under the hood it's probably doing something very comparable to what you're already doing, but mixing in some reflection to make it more generic.  What you're doing isn't terribly inefficient per se, unless you're talking about *really* high volume and need to squeeze out every ounce of performance possible.

Replacing the `DataTable` entirely with an ORM may also work for you.  [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) is a pretty common standard, though there are many others.  ([Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) is known for its fast performance, if that's what you're looking for.)

If the "time consuming" part isn't the runtime performance but rather the development time, I wouldn't worry a whole lot about it.  If you can spend some time abstracting the `DataTable`s behind a translation layer into POCO objects, the benefits will likely pay off in the long run.  It's a lot of menial code, but it's a one-time expense.

Comment: Thank you with this. I'll try this stuff. I'm familiar with EF but i can't use it since the project is not started by me. And this is already an existing system, just adding some stuffs.

Comment: @Rossana: If there's a possibility of moving toward a modern ORM in the future then building POCO models and abstracting the `DataTable`s behind some repositories could really help lay the foundation for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
public static List<T> ToModel<T>(this DataTable dt)
    {
        List<string> columns = (from DataColumn dc in dt.Columns select dc.ColumnName).ToList();

        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        List<T> lst = new List<T>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            var ob = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (var fieldInfo in fields.Where(fieldInfo => columns.Contains(fieldInfo.Name)))
            {
                fieldInfo.SetValue(ob, !dr.IsNull(fieldInfo.Name) ? dr[fieldInfo.Name] : fieldInfo.FieldType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(fieldInfo.FieldType) : null);
            }

            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties.Where(propertyInfo => columns.Contains(propertyInfo.Name)))
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(ob, !dr.IsNull(propertyInfo.Name) ? dr[propertyInfo.Name] : propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType) : null);
            }

            lst.Add(ob);
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

Comment: Could you also add some explanation?